# Game of life in JavaScript - using Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conways-game-of-life

I finished coding Conway's Game of Life in JavaScript and HTML table.
**logic** cells in a table will be assigned with unique `id's` and based on the `id` operations(based 4 rules) take place.
You can find the working code at [Codepen](http://codepen.io/SrSandeepKumar/pen/bNZMyg) or i have put the code below.
The thing is it works well with any number of rows and 9 columns and if more than 9 columns are given their wont be unique `id's` so it works in undesired manner.
**Query** Is their a way where i can assign the whole table with unique id's.
Code block `tableInitialization` is the initialization part.

```js
(function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var column = "", appendRow = "", inc = 1, selectedCells = [], toRemoveClass = [], toAddClass = [], maxValue;

  var tableInitialization = function(noOfRow, noOfColumn){
   for(var row=1; row<=noOfRow; row++){
    for(var col=1; col<=noOfColumn; col++){
     column += "<td  id =" + inc+col + ">  </td>";
    }
    appendRow += "<tr>"+column+"</tr>";
    column= "";
    inc++;
   }
    $(".table").append(appendRow);
  };

  $("#submit").click(function(data){
   var noOfRow = parseInt($("#rowNo").val());
   var noOfColumn = parseInt($("#columnNo").val());
   maxValue = parseInt(noOfRow.toString() + noOfColumn.toString());

   if(isNaN(noOfRow) || isNaN(noOfColumn)){
    alert("Please enter number");
   } else {
    tableInitialization(noOfRow, noOfColumn);
    $("#container").hide();
    $("td").click( function(data){
     selectedCells.push(parseInt(this.id));
     $(this).addClass("valid");
    });
   } 
  });

  

  var checkAgain = function(selectedCells){
   var check = 0, toBeReplaced = [], inArray = [], livingCell;
   var currentNumber = 0;
   var north, northEast, East, southEast, south, southWest, west, northWest;

   for(var i=0; i<selectedCells.length; i++){
    check = 0;
       currentNumber = parseInt(selectedCells[i]);

       if($("#"+(currentNumber)).hasClass("valid")){
     livingCell = true;
    } else {
     livingCell = false;
    }

       if(currentNumber > 0 && currentNumber < maxValue){
    
     /*North*/
     if((currentNumber-10) > 0 && (currentNumber-10) < maxValue){ 
      if($("#"+(currentNumber-10)).hasClass("valid")){
       check ++;
      }
     }

     /*North East*/
     if((currentNumber-9) > 0 && (currentNumber-9) < maxValue){ 
      if($("#"+(currentNumber-9)).hasClass("valid")){
       check ++;
      }
     }

     /*East*/
     if((currentNumber+1) > 0 && (currentNumber+1) < maxValue){ 
      if($("#"+(currentNumber+1)).hasClass("valid")){
       check ++;
      }
     }

     /*South East*/
     if((currentNumber+11) > 0 && (currentNumber+11) < maxValue){ 
      if($("#"+(currentNumber+11)).hasClass("valid")){
       check ++;
      }
     }

     /*South*/
     if((currentNumber+10) > 0 && (currentNumber+10) < maxValue){ 
      if($("#"+(currentNumber+10)).hasClass("valid")){
       check ++;
      }
     }

     /*South West*/
     if((currentNumber+9) > 0 && (currentNumber+9) < maxValue){ 
      if($("#"+(currentNumber+9)).hasClass("valid")){
       check ++;
      }
     }

     /*West*/
     if((currentNumber-1) > 0 && (currentNumber-1) < maxValue){ 
      if($("#"+(currentNumber-1)).hasClass("valid")){
       check ++;
      }
     }

     /*North West*/
     if((currentNumber-11) > 0 && (currentNumber-11) < maxValue){ 
      if($("#"+(currentNumber-11)).hasClass("valid")){
       check ++;
      }
     }

     if(livingCell){
      if(check === 0 || check === 1 ){
       if(toRemoveClass.indexOf(currentNumber) == -1){
        toRemoveClass.push(currentNumber);
       }
      } 
      if(check == 4 || check == 5 || check == 6 || check == 7 || check == 8 ){
       if(toRemoveClass.indexOf(currentNumber) == -1){
        toRemoveClass.push(currentNumber);
       }
      } 
      if(check == 2 || check == 3){
       if(toAddClass.indexOf(currentNumber) == -1){
        toAddClass.push(currentNumber);
       }
      } 
     } else {
      if(check == 3){
       if(toAddClass.indexOf(currentNumber) == -1){
        toAddClass.push(currentNumber);
       }
      } 
     }

    }
   }
  };

  var gol = function(selectedCells){
   var check = 0, inArray = [];
    var currentNumber = 0, livingCell;
   for(var i=0; i<selectedCells.length; i++){
     toBeReplaced = [];
     check = 0;
        currentNumber = parseInt(selectedCells[i]);

        if($("#"+(currentNumber)).hasClass("valid")){
      livingCell = true;
     } else {
      livingCell = false;
     }
        
        if(currentNumber > 0 && currentNumber < maxValue){
     
      /*North*/
      if((currentNumber-10) > 0 && (currentNumber-10) < maxValue){ 
       if($("#"+(currentNumber-10)).hasClass("valid")){
        check ++;
       }
      
       if(toBeReplaced.indexOf((currentNumber-10)) == -1){
        toBeReplaced.push(currentNumber-10);
       }
      }

      /*North East*/
      if((currentNumber-9) > 0 && (currentNumber-9) < maxValue){ 
       if($("#"+(currentNumber-9)).hasClass("valid")){
        check ++;
       }
      
       if(toBeReplaced.indexOf((currentNumber-9)) == -1){
        toBeReplaced.push(currentNumber-9);
       }
      }

      /*East*/
      if((currentNumber+1) > 0 && (currentNumber+1) < maxValue){ 
       if($("#"+(currentNumber+1)).hasClass("valid")){
        check ++;
       }

       if(toBeReplaced.indexOf((currentNumber+1)) == -1){
        toBeReplaced.push(currentNumber+1);
       }
      }

      /*South East*/
      if((currentNumber+11) > 0 && (currentNumber+11) < maxValue){ 
       if($("#"+(currentNumber+11)).hasClass("valid")){
        check ++;
       }

       if(toBeReplaced.indexOf((currentNumber+11)) == -1){
        toBeReplaced.push(currentNumber+11);
       }
      }

      /*South*/
      if((currentNumber+10) > 0 && (currentNumber+10) < maxValue){ 
       if($("#"+(currentNumber+10)).hasClass("valid")){
        check ++;
       }

       if(toBeReplaced.indexOf((currentNumber+10)) == -1){
        toBeReplaced.push(currentNumber+10);
       }
      }

      /*South West*/
      if((currentNumber+9) > 0 && (currentNumber+9) < maxValue){ 
       if($("#"+(currentNumber+9)).hasClass("valid")){
        check ++;
       }

       if(toBeReplaced.indexOf((currentNumber+9)) == -1){
        toBeReplaced.push(currentNumber+9);
       }
      }

      /*West*/
      if((currentNumber-1) > 0 && (currentNumber-1) < maxValue){ 
       if($("#"+(currentNumber-1)).hasClass("valid")){
        check ++;
       }

       if(toBeReplaced.indexOf((currentNumber-1)) == -1){
        toBeReplaced.push(currentNumber-1);
       }
      }

      /*North West*/
      if((currentNumber-11) > 0 && (currentNumber-11) < maxValue){ 
       if($("#"+(currentNumber-11)).hasClass("valid")){
        check ++;
       }

       if(toBeReplaced.indexOf((currentNumber-11)) == -1){
        toBeReplaced.push(currentNumber-11);
       }
      }

      if(livingCell){
       if(check == 0 || check == 1 ){
        if(toRemoveClass.indexOf(currentNumber) == -1){
         toRemoveClass.push(currentNumber);
        }
       } 
       if(check == 4 || check == 5 || check == 6 || check == 7 || check == 8 ){
        if(toRemoveClass.indexOf(currentNumber) == -1){
         toRemoveClass.push(currentNumber);
        }
       } 
       if(check == 2 || check == 3){
        if(toAddClass.indexOf(currentNumber) == -1){
         toAddClass.push(currentNumber);
        }
       } 
      } else {
       if(check == 3){
        if(toAddClass.indexOf(currentNumber) == -1){
         toAddClass.push(currentNumber);
        }
       } 
      }

     }
    checkAgain(toBeReplaced);
   }
   
   
   for(var i=0; i<toRemoveClass.length; i++){
    $("#"+toRemoveClass[i]).removeClass("valid");
   }
   
   for(var i=0; i<toAddClass.length; i++){
    $("#"+toAddClass[i]).addClass("valid");
   }
   
   toBeReplaced = toAddClass; 
   
   if(toAddClass.length == 0){
    //exit
    return;
   } else {
    setInterval(function(){
     gol($.unique(toBeReplaced));
    },1000);
   }
 
   selectedCells = [];
   toAddClass =[];
   toRemoveClass = [];
 
  };

  start = function(){
   if(selectedCells.length == 0){
    alert("select cell");
   } else {

    gol(selectedCells);

   }
  };

 });
})();
```

```css
body{
  background: #BBDEFB ;
}
td {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #eee;
}
table {
    cursor: default;
}
.valid {
    background: #00BFA5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Conways Game of Life</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gameOfLife.css">
</head>
<body>

 <h1><code>Conway's game of life</code></h1>
 <div id="container">
  <h2><code>enter row * columns</code></h2>
  <form>
   <code>row &#9733; column : </code>
   <input id="rowNo" type="text"/> &#9733;
   <input id="columnNo" type="text"/>
  </form>
  <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
     <br><br>
    </div>

 <table class="table"></table>
 <br><br>
 <button onClick="start()"> start </button>
 <br><br>
 <h2><code> Rules </code></h2>
 <code>1. Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, 
       as if caused by underpopulation.</code><br>
 <code>2. Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, 
    as if by overcrowding.</code><br>
 <code>3. Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives 
    on to the next generation.</code><br>
 <code>4. Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes 
    a live cell.</code>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="gameOfLife.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without digging really deep into your code. You build the IDs by using *col* and *row* index, so you'll get something like `11, 12, 13, 14, 15, ... 110, 111, 112` etc. for the first row. Without a delimiter the ID of the eleventh row first element would be 111 too. As soon as you use a kind of delimiter like '_' your IDs are unique: `1_1, 1_2` again.

```
for(var row=1; row<=noOfRow; row++){
    for(var col=1; col<=noOfColumn; col++){
        column += "<td id =" + inc+"_"+col + ">  </td>";
        /* you also could add data attributes:
           data-row=\""+row+"\" data-col=\""+col+"\" 
        */
    }
    appendRow += "<tr>"+column+"</tr>";
    column= "";
    inc++;
}
```

Looking into your code, I think you will get other problems, because there is a lot of code related to "10". For example: `if((currentNumber-9) > 0 && (currentNumber-9) < maxValue){` - this won't work in case you'll have more than 9 rows. But fixing this would be a rewritten version of the complete game.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Ya detecting the next cells(code related to "10") will give problems at stages, i think i have to tweak the code a bit to check the length of the `id` and operate based on that.

Comment: I have kind of completed it for any number of rows and columns, the code at codepen.io/SrSandeepKumar/pen/bNZMyg but when i try to get a `Glider Gun` it dint work as desired.